# Unable to load HPROF file in Eclipse Memory Analyser

Tags: java, eclipse, hprof, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I'm getting the below error while loading the HPROF file in MAT

*The HPROF parser encountered a violation of the HPROF specification that it could not safely handle. This could be due to file truncation or a bug in the JVM. Please consider filing a bug at eclipse.org. To continue parsing the dump anyway, you can use -DhprofStrictnessWarning=true or set the strictness mode under Preferences > HPROF Parser > Parser Strictness. See the inner exception for details.
The HPROF parser encountered a violation of the HPROF specification that it could not safely handle. This could be due to file truncation or a bug in the JVM. Please consider filing a bug at eclipse.org. To continue parsing the dump anyway, you can use -DhprofStrictnessWarning=true or set the strictness mode under Preferences > HPROF Parser > Parser Strictness. See the inner exception for details.
Heap dump record 0x20 size 15,93,39,104 is not a supported record type.
Heap dump record 0x20 size 15,93,39,104 is not a supported record type.*

After changing the preferences it is throwing the below error

*An internal error occurred during: "Parsing heap dump from '/home/local/ZOHOCORP/raamesh-1460/Downloads/Rajesh/java_pid2360.hprof'".
java.lang.NullPointerException*

**JDK version: 1.6**